# AngularJS UI Router: ui-sref not updating URL in address bar because parent state has StateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI Router and seem to be experiencing an odd issue. When I click a link that has a ui-sref directive attached to it, it successfully loads the new view as I would expect, HOWEVER, it does not update the URL bar. I believe this is ocurring because the parent state's url is a dynamic StateParam `/:room`. How do I get around this issue?

**Here is a snippet of my UI Router**

```
// Room
.state({
  name: 'room',
  url: "/:room",
  views: {
    "main": {
      templateUrl: "views/pages/chat.html",
      controller: "RoomCtrl"
    },
    "login@room": {
      templateUrl: "views/partials/_login.html"
    },
    "navigation@room": {
      templateUrl: "views/partials/_navigation.html",
      controller: "NavigationCtrl"
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    userLocation: function(geolocationFactory) {
      return geolocationFactory;
    }
  }
})

// Share
.state({
  name: 'room.share',
  url: "/share",
  views: {
    "share@room": {
      templateUrl: "views/partials/_share.html",
      controller: "ShareCtrl"
    }
  }
});
```

**ui-sref**
`<button id="share-button" ui-sref="room.share">Share</button>`

Answer (score 3):

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Izc7RprF33Jnpw5QGD7S?p=preview) to demonstrate what is happening

So we can navigate among rooms like this:

```
<a ui-sref="room({room:1})">room 1</a>
<a ui-sref="room({room:2})">room 2</a>
<a ui-sref="room({room:3})">room 3</a>
```

this will in fact creat the url like this

```
#/1      // where 1 represents the id of the :room
#/2      
#/3
```

Now, we can navigate to the substate `.share` without specifying the `:room` id

```
<a ui-sref="room.share">room.share</a>
```

And what will happen? Firstly the place for `:room` will be empty ... no room is selected.

Secondly - the previously selected room *(its `:room` id)* won't be changed. So the resulting URL will depend on the already selected room. If we were in a room 2, the generated url will be:

```
#//share
```

but we will be redirected to

```
#/2/share
```

becuase there is still $stateParams.room === 2

Finally, **we should always pass the complete state signature**:

```
<a ui-sref="room.share({room:1})">room.share({room:1})</a>
<a ui-sref="room.share({room:2})">room.share({room:2})</a>
<a ui-sref="room.share({room:3})">room.share({room:3})</a>
```

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Izc7RprF33Jnpw5QGD7S?p=preview) *(click the top right corner blue icon to open the prview in sepearate window with url)*

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my parameter names did not match my URL definition.

For example, I had a parameter set like this:

```
{
    page: {...},
    results: {...},
    sort: {...},
}
```

...and a URL like this:

```
url: '/foo?page&results&orderby'
```

After fixing the mismatch between `sort` and `orderby`, the address bar updated as expected.